# How to compile f# fable code to a multiple parameter javascript function

Tags: javascript, f#, transpiler, fable-f#

Hi I am attempting to make som rudimentary bindings for a database written in java, which ideally I would want to actually use in F#. However I am fairly unfamiliar with javascript. I have managed to get the binding to work with 1 argument however multiple arguments crashes the program due to trying to call a function with 1 argument when you need 3.

The code:

```
type IRNCouchDBs =
    abstract member Add : string*string*((string)->string)

[<Import("CouchDB", from = "NativeModules")>]
let couchDB : IRNCouchDBs = jsNative
```

Add in this case is in java and is essentially:

```
@ReactMethod 
public void Add (String name, String type, Callback cb)
```

if I call the f# code like so

```
 let str (s : string)  =  s //just a test function
couchDB.Add ("name", "type", (str "test"))
```

then the error occurs which complains that I am trying to pass a 1 argument function into a multiple argument function.

Any ideas how to solve this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, fairly obvious in retrospect.

```
type IRNCouchDBs =
    abstract member Add : Func<string, string, ((string*string->string)), unit>

[<Import("CouchDB", from = "NativeModules")>]
let couchDB : IRNCouchDBs = jsNative


let f' = (fun (x :string,y ) -> (x + y))
couchDB.Add.Invoke (fish.FishType,fish.Name, f')
```

Used Func, and invoked it which seems to be the way to do it.